# Piwik returns 400 bad request when trying to send tracking data via API

Tags: java, analytics, matomo

I'm developing an app which I plan on implementing Piwik Analytics into. Although there seems to be no real documentation (unless I'm blind) on how to use the Java Tracking API ([this one](https://github.com/piwik/piwik-java-tracking)), I think I managed to figure it out, but when I try it, I get this error

```
WARNING: Warning:400 Bad Request
org.piwik.PiwikException: error:400 Bad Request
at org.piwik.SimplePiwikTracker.sendRequest(SimplePiwikTracker.java:878)
at test.Main.main(Main.java:32)
```

Here is my code:

```
SimplePiwikTracker tracker = new SimplePiwikTracker("http://example.com/piwik/piwik.php");
tracker.setIdSite(2);
tracker.setPageUrl("http://example.com/javatest/test");
tracker.setPageCustomVariable("test", "10");

//This is line 32
tracker.sendRequest(tracker.getLinkTrackURL("http://example.com/piwik/piwik.php"));
```

I also tried this:

```
String datURL = tracker.getLinkTrackURL("http://example.com/piwik/piwik.php").toString();
URL url = new URL(datURL);          
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
System.out.println(connection.getResponseCode());
connection.disconnect();
```

But this just prints out response code `404` which doesn't make any sense because if I paste the link generated by `tracker.getLinkTrackURL` into my browser it works perfectly and logs correctly in Piwik (I have debug mode on).

So my question is, why is Piwik returning a bad request and why can't Java find the URL (404) when it works perfectly fine in my browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Instead of having the URL point to the `http://example.com/piwik/piwik.php`, it should just be going to `http://example.com/piwik`